# min not working in python pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have tried the following code:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(pct, values=['CERT'], index=['ST'], aggfunc={'CERT': [min, max, np.mean]})
```

and received the following error:

```
sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'
```

However, when I ran the following code and it worked:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(pct, values=['CERT'], index=['ST'], aggfunc={'CERT': [max, np.mean]})
```

The only difference being I have removed the min function. I find this really puzzling and would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Also, if anyone does know how to perform this analysis only on the states with two or more entries, that would also be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that you'd defined a global or local `min` that's shadowing the builtin? What happens if you `print(min, max, np.mean)`?

Comment: Also, can you give us the complete traceback, instead of just the exception description?

Comment: @abarnert, you are correct I had defined a global min earlier. Need to look out for defining common keywords as functions in the future. Thanks again. Do you have any suggestions on how to only apply the pivot table to states with more than 1 entry (i.e. corresponding CERT  value)

Comment: That's a completely separate question, so create a new question instead of trying to get it answered in the comments of this one. (Most of the Pandas experts probably aren't reading here.)

Comment: By the way, when I'm working in a long-running interactive session, I make this mistake all the time (and don't notice until I run into the problem 3 days later). A helpful trick: `globals().keys() & dir(builtins)` should show you only a few special dunder names like `__doc__`, and maybe `get_ipython`. If you see anything else, like `min`, you've shadowed a builtin.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it works if I put min within hiphens

pivot = pd.pivot_table(pct, values=['CERT'], index=['ST'], aggfunc={'CERT': ['max','min', np.mean]})